# What is std equivalent of boost cpu timer

Tags: c++, boost, timer, c++-chrono

I would like to migrate [boost::timer::cpu_timer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html) in my code to standard library solution. I only found [std::chrono::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) but it doesn't offer the same functionality as boost variant. What I basically need is wall and system time output, e.g.

```
5.713010s wall, 5.709637s user + 0.000000s system = 5.709637s CPU (99.9%)
```

Is there anything like this in standard library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing in C++ standard library which would measure system and user time. You can only get wall time with `std::chrono::` functions (of which `steady_clock` would be the most approriate to measure time intervals).